# LibreOffice - Data - Validity - Criteria - How to use formula option?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, i need to find a way to validate if entered data has more then one line.

I check this:
https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/12120100.html

But there is no description how to use "Formula" ?

Could somebody help me in finding a way to do that ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "if entered data has more then one line", what do you mean by that? Please show some examples and expected results?

Comment: In first screenshot in ROW #2 there are VALID and INVALID data examples

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic validity formula example. It works even if 1 is after a newline in the cell.

```
NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("1";A2)))
```

This works as well.

```
NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(CHAR(10);"1" & CHAR(10) & "2")))
```

Also when entered as a normal formula in the spreadsheet, this works.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(CHAR(10);A2)))
```

So this should work as a validity formula, right? Sadly no, it doesn't.

```
NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(CHAR(10);A2)))
```

Comment: I posted this at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/314291/calc-validity-formula-matching-a-newline/ to see if anyone there can help.

Comment: suplemented https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/314291/calc-validity-formula-matching-a-newline/?answer=314358#post-id-314358